# C++: No default constructor exists for parent class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am writing the class file for a binary search tree (BST), which extends from the class (Tree). However, I receive the following error in my IDE for the current file (`bst.cpp`)

[image]
stating:

> no default constructor exists for class "Tree"

In compilation, I receive the following error:

> no matching function for call to ‘Tree::Tree()’

This seems strange, considering that I have already defined a default constructor in my Tree class implementation and have imported the class into my `bst.cpp` file:

```
// Import dependencies
#include "datastructure.hpp"
#include "tree.cpp"

// Import libraries
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

BST::BST() {
    
}

void BST::solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path)
{
}
```

Below is `datastructure.hpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef struct TreeNode { 
   int key;
   int val;
   bool flag;
   int num_children;
   TreeNode **children;
} TreeNode; 

class Tree {
    protected:
        TreeNode* root;
        int max_width;
    public:
        Tree(int width);
        static void solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path);

};

class BST: public Tree {
    protected:
        int max_width = 2;
        
    public:
        BST();
        static void solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path);
};
```

And finally, below is my `tree.cpp`:

```
#include "datastructure.hpp"

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <queue> 

using namespace std;

Tree::Tree(int width) {
    max_width = width;
}

void Tree::solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path)
{
}
```

Comment: As stated, `Tree` does not have the default constructor. Either provide it or make `BST()` calling `Tree(int)`. The default constructor is not automatically generated in case you define one.

Comment: @karastojko How would I translate making BST() calling Tree(int) into syntax?

Comment: When calling BST(), it automatically invokes the base constructor as Tree() which does not exist.

Comment: `#include "tree.cpp"` Is it a typo for `#include "tree.hpp"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it there, `Tree` does not have a default constructor. As a result of that, you cannot default-construct a `BST`, because the `Tree` that is inside it will not know how to construct itself.

You have to member-initialize it.

```
BST::BST() : Tree(1) {}
```

Are you sure you don't want to pass that value to the constructor of `BST` though?

```
BST::BST(int w) : Tree(w) {}
```